# Event Listening from Child to Parent in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I want to send an event from a child component to its parent, which should change the view.

I am able to create the event and emit it, however my template does not seem to be registering it, I am using Single File Components (SFC). Also if I manually update the data object all works fine.

App.vue (Parent)

```
<template>
    <div v-on:change-view="updateView">
        <!-- render the currently active component/page here -->
        <component v-bind:is="currentView"></component>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name : 'app',
  data () {
      return {
          currentView : 'Modal'
      }
  },
  methods : {
      updateView (view) {
          console.log('event listener!!!')
          this.currentView = view;
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Modal.vue (Child)

```
<template>
    <div> 
        <vk-modal v-bind:show="show">
            <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
            <p>{{ body }}</p>
            <p class="uk-text-right">
                <vk-button v-on:click="$emit('change-view', 'Purposes')">More Information</vk-button>
                <vk-button v-on:click="fullConsent" type="primary">I Agree</vk-button>
            </p>
        </vk-modal> 
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name : 'modal',
  data () {
      return {
          show : true,
          title : 'Hello'
      }
  },
  methods : {
        fullConsent () {
            this.show = false;
        }
  }
}
</script>
```

Please help :)

Comment: Is Purposes component available in App.vue, ie registered as global component? Otherwise it must be registered as local component.

Comment: I am calling `Vue.component('Purposes', Purposes);` in main.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to register the event listener on the `<component>` itself; component events do not bubble ([unlike DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture)).

```vue
<div>
    <component v-bind:is="currentView" v-on:change-view="updateView"></component>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there also a way I can do this via the JS (methods) itself, both create an event and listen?

Comment: If you have a reference to a component (via [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)), then you can add a listener with [`$on`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on), see [Programmatic Event Listeners](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Programmatic-Event-Listeners).